# Control of electric hoist motor based on variable load

Tags: power, motor, control

Is it possible to control the power of a hoist motor based on the specific load that will be lifted? What if the load is known by using a weight sensor?

Comment: Control the power to do what?

Comment: Not without a much clearer idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think he wants to actively hold a weight without a brake, and use that as a dynamic "neutral point" of some other controller.  If so, then yes, it's possible, but the primary risk from a controls perspective is going to be `positive feedback` causing the system to oscillate.

Comment: If you intend to hold a weight without a break it is possible but most probably prohibited. You can not control the situation in case of a power failure

Comment: Dr, & brothers , my idea is to let the motor of hoist to generate specific toque or power to raise known load which will be measured by the weight sensor

Comment: In that case, yes, it is possible. Not necessarily desirable, but possible.

Comment: Thank mr jonh ,,in fact I'm doing my final project for my bachelor degree in mechatronic engineering in this topic control the torque for desirable load 

Comment: Motor torque is proportional to current, so a current control loop can control torque.  You might want an outer control loop that controls angular or linear speed based on a transducer of some sort.  A weight sensor doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: I was reviewing "close" votes and stumbled upon this. It's weird - on one hand there is nothing wrong with the question. It is precise, it has definite not opinion-based answer "yes, it is possible". And yet... it seems so pointless that I can't help but wonder if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Electronic controls can control all of the various aspects of motor performance, but the natural relationship among the various aspects limits the ability to control them. The control system must also be limited by the physical capabilities of the motor. In addition, the characteristics of the load impose limits on the performance of the motor. In choosing to control torque, you must remember that you can no longer control speed except to set maximum and minimum speed limits. When these limits are reached, torque control is no longer in effect. You can also have a torque control loop inside a speed control loop. The choice of control strategy is made with consideration of the nature of the driven machine.

You need to think about speed, torque, power and acceleration rate. Determine how these are related to the characteristics of the motor and load. Define what overall performance benefit will be gained by controlling torque. Determine if torque should be the primary adjustment that should be set by the operator.

The electronic control can be configured to do anything you want it to do. What needs to be done is to determine how the driven equipment can best be used by the operator. Then determine how to implement a control system to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, motors inherently consume power based on the load they're connected to. If you take a DC motor and spin it at a constant voltage with 'no load', it will reach a steady state where it spins at the maximum speed for that voltage and a low current. If you add a small constant load, the current will slightly increase while the voltage remains the same.

Assuming you're not particularly concerned with *how fast* the hoist can lift things (i.e. it's slow enough at no-load that a human operator can control it easily with two buttons), you can just reduce the speed of whatever motor you're using down using some mechanism that gives you mechanical advantage (i.e. gearbox) until it's slow enough to be controllable by eye. This is likely how most off the shelf hoist systems work.

If you want to automate control of the hoist, control speed or control the height precisely, you'll want to close a PID loop on *position*. This means your setpoint will be something like a motor angular position (error measured with an encoder) or height off the ground (can measure with encoder and some math, a camera, rangefinder, etc.). In this scenario, the motor will only consume the amount of power your controller calls for to track your requested target position. In fact, if you know the motor Kv rating, some characteristics of the mechanism (rope thickness, number of turns before it overlaps), and can measure the motor current, you can use the motor itself to calculate the weight of your load.